# PyAudio - multiple channel management \ Demixing

Tags: python, audio, raspberry-pi, pyaudio, cross-correlation

I want to calculate the single channel data (in order to calculate the audio cross correlation between the channel 1 and channel 4) of this code:

```
import time
import numpy as np
import pyaudio
import scipy
from scipy import signal, fftpack

pyaud = pyaudio.PyAudio()


#open the stream

stream = pyaud.open(
    format = pyaudio.paInt16,
    channels = 4,
    rate = 16000,
    input_device_index = 4,
    output = False,
    input = True,
    frames_per_buffer=2048,)


while True:

    rawsamps = stream.read(2048)        
    samps = np.fromstring(rawsamps, dtype=np.int16)
    frames_per_buffer_length = len(samps) / 4 #(channels)   
    assert frames_per_buffer_length == int(frames_per_buffer_length)    
    samps = np.reshape(samps, (frames_per_buffer_length, 4)) #4 channels
```

Assuming that the raw data is interleaved.
This is the function i need to use :

```
    signal.correlate(n1, n2, mode='full')
```

how can I create an array of data for each channel in order to use the correlate function? are the last lines of the code correct?

Thank you

Comment: You seem to be asking the same question [over](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41922139/) and [over](http://stackoverflow.com/q/42027487/) again. I suggest you should start smaller and first learn a few basics about NumPy (there are a lot of good tutorials available online). You might want to have a look at [this](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/mgeier/python-audio/blob/master/simple-signals.ipynb) and [that](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/mgeier/python-audio/blob/master/audio-files/audio-files-with-wave.ipynb).

Comment: Once you've done that, you can have another look at the [example](https://github.com/spatialaudio/python-sounddevice/blob/master/examples/plot_input.py) I've shown you before.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, using `print loudness(samps[:,0]), loudness(samps[:,3])`. It print in the shell " mic 1 loudness , mic 4 loudness"